# Are there real numbers a and b such that $f(x,y,t) = x^a t^b$ satisfies the heat equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

The question is in the title. The heat equation is as follows:
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial t} = k \left( \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2} +  \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y^2} \right),\quad k\in\mathbb{R}
$$

---

*Attempt at solution*

Plugging the requested form into the above equation yields:

$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial t} = b\ t^{b-1} x^a\\
\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2} = a (a-1)\ t^b x^{a-2}\\
\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y^2} = 0
$$

Which leads to showing that:
$$
b\ x^2 = k\ a(a-1)\ t
$$

I'm not sure how to proceed from this point. Is this the correct procedure to solve this problem? Thanks!

Comment: My answer below wasn't detailed enough, if you must mark a solution, mark the one of nbubis ;)

Comment: Thanks to both of you anyway!  Its pretty obvious now that I look at the simplified answer.  How was bx2=k a(a−1) t obtained?

Comment: By simple substitution in the heat equation; the exponents of $x$ and $t$ on both sides can be simplified, that's all I did :)

Comment: Thanks! I guess I'm a little rusty on my more basic maths haha.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that for your condition to be satisfied for all $x,t$, since $x$ and $t$ are independent, the only way for the condition to hold would be for both sides to be equal zero, leading to:
$$b = 0, a = 0,1$$

Answer (score 2):

From your derivations, it seems to me that $b=0$ and $a=1$ would work fine for instance...